# Why are $\frac{1}{\cos \theta}+\tan{\theta}$ and $\frac{1}{\cos\theta}-\tan{\theta}$ always reciprocals (besides simply multiplying to get $1$)?

Tags: trigonometry

Can anybody help me understand why these terms are always reciprocals? (theta <= 45°)

$$ x =  \frac{1}{\cos \theta} + \tan{\theta} $$
$$ \frac{1}{x} =  \frac{1}{\cos \theta} - \tan{\theta} $$

I understand that if we multiply them, they equal $1$ (because of the equation for a circle).

$$\begin{align}
1 &= (\frac{1}{\cos \theta} + \tan{θ})(\frac{1}{\cos \theta} - \tan{θ}) \\[4pt]
1 &= \frac{1}{(\cos{\theta})^{2}} - \frac{\tan{\theta}}{\cos{\theta}} +  \frac{\tan{\theta}}{\cos{\theta}} - (\tan{\theta})^2 \\[4pt]
1 &= \frac{1}{(\cos{\theta})^2} - (\tan{\theta})^2 \\[4pt]
(\cos{\theta})^2 &= 1 - (\cos{\theta})^2(\tan{\theta})^2 \\[4pt]
(\cos{\theta})^2 &= 1 - (\sin{\theta})^2 
\end{align}$$

But I am looking for a deeper understanding? Regards

Comment: I would say the Pythagorean theorem/parametrization of the unit circle *is* the deep reason, and almost every basic trigonometric identity boils down to this.

Comment: You don't even need to use trigonometry here, really; you can write $x^2 + y^2 = 1 \implies 1 - y^2 = x^2 \implies 1/x^2 - y^2 = 1 \implies (1/x- y)(1/x + y) = 1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a theorem (or set of theorems) of geometry called the
[Power of a Point](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Power_of_a_Point_Theorem).
Note that this theorem is easily proved [without using any trigonometry](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/PPower.shtml).

[image]

A particular case of the power of a point says that if you have a line through the point $A$ that is tangent to a circle at $B,$
and another line through $A$ that intersects the same circle at $C$ and $D,$
as shown in the figure above, then

$$ AB^2 = AC \cdot AD. $$

Now lets add some more specific properties to the figure. First, suppose we take the distance $AB$ as our unit of length, so $AB = 1.$
Next, suppose $\angle BAC = \theta.$
Finally, suppose the line $AD$ passes through the center of the circle, $O$.

[image]

Now $BO = \tan \theta$ and $AO = \frac{1}{\cos\theta} = \sec \theta$.
Observe that $AC = \sec\theta - \tan\theta$ and that $AD = \sec\theta + \tan\theta$.
Recalling the formula for the power of a point in a case like this,
$AB^2 = AC \cdot AD,$
and putting the particular lengths of the segments in this example into that formula,
we find that

$$ 1^2 = (\sec\theta - \tan\theta)(\sec\theta + \tan\theta), $$

and therefore

$$ \sec\theta - \tan\theta = \frac{1}{\sec\theta + \tan\theta}. $$

So your trigonometric identity is simply a special case of the power of a point.
Note that it is not restricted only to $0 \leq \theta \leq 45^\circ.$
The geometric theorem shows that the identity is true for any acute angle.

If you use the usual definition of trigonometric functions for angles outside the range from zero to a right angle, the identity is good for all angles for which the cosine is not zero. But that takes a bit more interpretation if you want to make something geometric out of it. (In particular, you have to deal with the fact that the cosine and tangent are sometimes negative.)

Comment: perfect. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Proof:

If $$x = \sec \theta + \tan \theta \ (\text {here} \sec \theta = \dfrac {1}{\cos \theta})$$

Then $$ \dfrac {1}{x} = \dfrac {1}{\sec \theta+\tan \theta}$$

Rationalizing the denominator by multiplying by $\sec \theta - \tan \theta$ we have $$ \dfrac {1}{x} = \dfrac {\sec \theta-\tan \theta}{\sec^2 \theta - \tan^2 \theta}$$

As $\sec^2 \theta - \tan^2 \theta = 1$ via the Pythagorean theorem, we then have $$ \dfrac {1}{x} = {\sec \theta-\tan \theta}.$$