# Is the angle of the 345 triangle (pythagorean triple) related to the Geometric Progression. 4, 2, 1, 1/2, 1/4?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, pythagorean-triples

I realised recently I could use this [equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292114/can-anybody-provide-any-information-about-this-equation-22-leftx-frac1) for the pythagorean triples.

[image: pythagorean triples]

As you can see the 345 triangle seems to be special? as we can create it using x=2 AND x=3.

[image: 345 triangle]

I know the 345 triangle is related to this golden triangle.

[image]

Using the theorem of geometry called the [Power of a Point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4138292/why-are-frac1-cos-theta-tan-theta-and-frac1-cos-theta-tan-the).

[image]

why is there a square-root relationship here**?**

Is it correct to say that the angle of the 345 triangle is related to the Geometric Progression. 4, 2, 1, 1/2, 1/4 where x = (a+b) = 2 and 1/x = (a-b) = 1/2, x^2 = 4 and 1/x^2 = 1/4, x^4 = 16 and 1/x^4 = 1/16 and therefore the square as shown below**?**

[image]

We find the 345 triangle in the construction of the square as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Besides, the "equation" you mention is in fact a consequence of the general formula $a=(m^2-n^2),b=2mn,c=(m^2+n^2)$ for pythagorean triples with $x=\frac{m}{n}$.

Comment: @JeanMarie yes, sorry I dont know the correct words to use. geometrical squares with perimeters  4,2,1. (a+b) = x = 2 and (a-b) = 1/x = 1/2 and x^2 = 2 and 1/x^2  = 1/4 etc.  I am looking for an angle that i can say represents these 'square' numbers and the geometric square taking into account these reciprocals. Does this make any more sense? thankyou for commenting.

Comment: You probably know that the name for a sequence like $4,2,1,1/2,1/4...$ is "Geometric Progression" (abbreviation GP): the next term is obtained from the previous one by multiplying it by a fixed quantity, called the ratio of the GP, here $r=\tfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I am still not fully understanding your (interesting!) drawings. Can you confirm in particular that the last representation of a square within a square is meant as 2 "russian dolls" as I called them, and that the process will continue, with a third smaller russian doll, etc... But is the 3-4-5 triangle present in this construction ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I have updated the question, thank you for your time. Yes, i want to be able to keep the integrity of these "russian dolls" or the reciprocals (a+b) and (a-b) intact.

Comment: I resisted downvoting for the word "ect".

Comment: Your new drawings bring indeed much clarity to your issue. Now, what is exactly your question ? Do you want to know : 1) if this issue is connected to "higher or different" mathematics 2) can it be generalized to other triangles or is it specific to the 3-4-5 triangle 3) whether this construction has already been by chance given elsewhere ?

Comment: @GEdgar We belong to the [old school](https://withoutbullshit.com/blog/i-hate-etc-i-e-and-e-g-you-should-too-heres-how-to-fix-them)...

Comment: Note: "etc" is fine, but not "ect".

Comment: @JeanMarie I want to know if i can say that this angle (theta) 'represents' the geometric progression (4,2,1,1/2,1/4) where the GP ratio = 1/ (a+b) and (a−b)? amd why is there a square-root relationship between the 2 triangles as shown? thank you for your time.

Comment: Have a look at the very nice long article [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/GoldenRatio.shtml) where you will have a lot of such constructions, some of them related to the "ubiquitous 3-4-5 triangle" as they name it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Euclid's formula in another form
shown here
$$A=(m^2-k^2)\quad B=2mk\quad C=m^2+k^2)$$
I use $\space F(m,k)\space $
but others use
$\quad F(m,n),\space F(p,q),\space F(s,t), \cdots$

In this case,
$\space m=x,\space k=1
  \quad A=\bigg(x-\frac{1}{x}\bigg)
 \quad B=2^2
 \quad C= \bigg(x+\frac{1}{x}\bigg)^2\quad$
and we shall see how it transforms back to Euclid's formula by multiplying each of the three terms by $\space x^2.$

\begin{align*}
2^2 &= \bigg(x+\frac{1}{x}\bigg)^2 
- \bigg(x-\frac{1}{x}\bigg)^2 
\\
\bigg(x-\frac{1}{x}\bigg)^2
+2^2 
&= \bigg(x+\frac{1}{x}\bigg)^2 
\\
\big(x^2-1\big)^2+\big(2x(1)\big)^2 &= \big(x^2+1\big)^2 
\\
A^2+B^2&=C^2
\end{align*}

What this formula $\space F(m,1)\space $ generates is
\begin{align*}
&F(2,1)=(3,4,5),\quad
F(3,1)=(8,6,10),\\
&F(4,1)=(15,8,17),\quad
F(5,1)=(24,10,26),\\
&F(6,1)=(35,12,37),\quad
F(7,1)=(48,14,50),\\
&F(8,1)=(63,16,65),\quad
F(9,1)=(80,18,82),\\
&F(10,1)=(99,20,101),\quad
F(11,1)=(120,22,122),\space \cdots
\end{align*}
These are not your results and note that every other triple is imprimitive.

Is the golden ration related to
$\space(3,4,5)?$

Given
$\space\tan^{-1}(\phi) \approx \tan^{-1}(1.61803398874989)
\approx  58.28^\circ
\\\longrightarrow 
F(617,344)=(262353,424496,499025)\\
\dfrac{424496}{262353}\approx 1.61803371792966 
$

$$
(3,4,5)\longrightarrow \tan^{-1} (1.333\space\cdots)
\approx 53.13^\circ\\
\longrightarrow 
F(2,1)=(3,4,5)$$

Comment: I have updated my question to show the phi relationship. Thankyou for commenting I will  respond when i am home.